# A view component named 'Search' could not be found

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a runtime error with this message

> InvalidOperationException: A view component named 'Search' could not be found. A view component must be a public non-abstract class, not contain any generic parameters, and either be decorated with 'ViewComponentAttribute' or have a class name ending with the 'ViewComponent' suffix. A view component must not be decorated with 'NonViewComponentAttribute'.

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The code you provide has nothing done with the ViewComponent. Have you created the `Search` ViewComponent?

For how to create a viewcomponent, usually you can follow the below steps.

1.Create a folder named `ViewComponents` in the root path, then create the ViewComponent class (SearchViewComponent). Note, it must end with ViewComponent.

```
public class SearchViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        
        return View();
    }
}
```

2.Add a folder named `Components` under Views > Shared folder, and add a folder named `Search`(corresponding to your ViewComponent class) under `Components` folder, then create the View, you can simply name it as `Default.cshtml`.

**Default.cshtml:**

For test, I simply set this in the View:

```
<h2>Search Content</h2>
```

[image]

3.Use the following to call ViewComponent:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Search")
```

Example:

Home Index View:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>

@await Component.InvokeAsync("Search")
```

Result:

[image]

For more details, refer to the [offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: Hi @Mahyar, if my reply is helpful, could you please [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), thanks!